# Understanding strings and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Consider this code.

```
int main()
{
    char *s, *t;

    s = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(s, "foo");
    t = s;
    printf("%s %s\n", s, t);         // Output --> foo foo
    strcpy(s, "bar"); // s = "bar"
    printf("%s %s\n", s, t);         // Output --> bar bar
}
```

There are 2 strings `s` and `t`. First I set `s` to `"foo"` and then make `t` point to `s`. When I print the strings, I get `foo foo`.

Then, copy `"bar"` to`s` and print again, I get `bar bar`.

Why does value of `t` changes in this case? (I copied `"bar"` to `s` why did `t` change).

---

Now when I change `strcpy(s, "bar")` to `s = "bar"` -

```
int main()
{
    char *s, *t;

    s = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(s, "foo");
    t = s;
    printf("%s %s\n", s, t); // Output --> foo foo
    s = "bar"
    printf("%s %s\n", s, t); // Output --> bar foo
}
```

This code gives me `foo foo` and `bar foo`.

Why didn't it change in this case?

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Play nice. Keep the comments on topic (meaning they should be asking for clarification).  If you want to open a discussion about the merits of this question, go [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I have removed the second part of your question, if you still want to ask it, make a separate post. You should ask only one question per post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means anything can happen:

```
char *s, *t;
strcpy(s, "foo");
```

as `strcpy()` is writing to a random location in memory because `s` is an uninitialised pointer.

---

(*after edit that corrected undefined behaviour*)

> **Question 1** - Why does value of t changes in this case? (I copied "bar" to s why did t change).

This is a pointer assignment:

```
t = s;
```

and results in both `t` and `s` pointing to the same memory that was `malloc()` and assigned to `s` earlier. Any change to that memory is visible via both `t` and `s`.

> **Question 2** - Why isn't t changing in the second case?

This assigns the address of the string literal `"bar"` to `s`:

```
s = "bar";
```

so now `t` and `s` do not point to the same memory location. `t` points to the memory that was earlier `malloc()` and assigned to `s` (because of the `t = s;` pointer assignment).

`strcpy()` and `=` are *very* different:

- `strcpy()` copies characters to the memory address specified by its first argument
- assignment, `=`, changes the address which a pointer holds

Comment: Ok, I have `malloc`ed now... still the same problem.

Comment: And why didn't it change in the 2nd case?

Comment: So whenever I create a string literal, it creates a new location in the memory? Like `s = "bar"`, would first create a `"bar"` in a new location and then assign it to `s`?

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya, basically yes. String literals will be stored, in a read-only location, as part of binary produced during compilation.

Comment: Does assignment changes the address only with strings and arrays or with an other data type too. Please check this out - http://codepad.org/j4JwKfeU. Assignment does not change the address of the integer in this case.

Comment: @ShuklaSannidhya, that is because `x` is not a pointer. A pointer of any type stores a memory address.

Answer (score 2):

```
strcpy(s, "foo");
```

Copies `foo` to memory location pointed to by `s`
    t = s;
Now, `t` and `s` both point to same location
Hence, same output

Now, you copy `bar` to `s`. Since both `t` and `s` point to same location. Hence, same output again.

---

Upto this line everything is same

```
s = "bar"
```

You create a string constant `bar`. And assign its address to `s`. Its a `pointer` it can point to any memory location. not necessarily the original one.

Now,

`s` points to `bar` and `t` still to the earlier location it pointed to in the beginning and hence the output

Answer (score 2):

a simplistic way to understand could be as follows :-

```
      s = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));    // this will be interpreted as follows 
      s = 123 ------------>|   |   |   |   | //some garbage values at these location
                           123  124 125 126   // some random address chosen.

      strcpy(s, "foo") ; // it copies at the address provided by s i.e.
                             |'f'|'o'|'o'|'\0'|
                              123 124 125  126 

      t = s;      this statement means t it pointing to address = 123

      strcpy(s, "bar"); // this statement copies at given address it means it will   override previous value .   i.e
                            |'b'|'a'|'r'|'\0'|
                             123 124 125 126
```

now t still pointing to address 123 that is why t, s both prints bar .

```
       s = "bar"  // this will  assign a new address to s which is base address of "bar" string . i.e .          
                           |'b'|'a'|'r'|'\0'|
                            321 322 323 324
```

now s will contain address 321 while t has value 123 that is why s and t are giving different values .